# Install, configure and use Wordpress in elementary OS

Tags: software-installation, web-development, settings

Can I install, configure and use wordpress to build a website on elementary OS? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely!

I'm assuming that you want to set up a local development environment for WordPress. If you want to set up a public web server, I'd recommend using a server-oriented distribution, or going with a hosted service such as WPEngine or Digital Ocean.

You could set up WordPress directly on Elementary, but it's easier and arguably a little cleaner to set it up inside a virtual machine. To do this:

1. Open Software Center.
2. Search for and install Virtualbox.
3. Search for and install Vagrant.
4. Follow the instructions in ["The first Vagrant Up"](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV#the-first-vagrant-up) to install VVV, an open source WordPress Vagrant configuration. Start with step 4. (You've already done the first 3 steps!)